# Dependency in test samples

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing

In the classification, we give the classifier test samples one by one. The assumption here is that the current test sample is independent of the previous one. The question is what if the current test sample and previous one are dependent.

Is there any machine learning technique to address this? or is there any way to give a feedback to classifier from previous sample to improve the detection in the current sample?

Comment: Could you give us examples of dependent and independent input examples to the classifier?

Comment: for example, visited pages in the website, when someone is visiting a website, with high chance the next visited page is a link on that website,